# Kohana or Mustache can not render new line <br/>?

Tags: html, kohana, newline, mustache

I use Kohana 3 + Kostache (Mustache for Kohana plugin).
At some point I create string:

```
$addStr .= "<br/>";
$addStr .= $sumrow['name'].": ".$sumrow['counter'];
```

and then string is putted into table. The table is then rendered by a Mustache. Unfortunately the `<br/>` tags are not rendered properly but are rendered as a regular text (`&lt;` and `&gt;`).

Is there a way to force Mustache or Kohana to not escape tags but just render them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got it. I had to just put `{{{addStr}}}` into my .mustache template file.

Comment: I'd be careful with this as it also allows people to inject javascript into the variable. (assuming the variable is coming from user input?)